# Laravel ORM query where with two columns and differents tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm new in Laravel and maybe could be silly

1.- Query with two tables and using two columns in each table

```
class Post extends Model {

    public function Comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

}
```

Figure out the Post model has the column `type`. I want to consult where `type = 1` and `title = foo`(comment model).The below example only has the title.

```
$comments = Post::find(1)->comments()->where('title', '=', 'foo')->first();
```

2.- My second question, Is there a way to run the orm queries without running or render the application. I mean like sqlplus or mysql terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1: *I want to consult where type = 1 and title = foo(comment model).*

**A1:** [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

---

```
// From the docs 

$users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
}])->get();



// So in your case - 

$comments = App\Comment::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('type', '=', 1); // Constraints on the Post model
})->where('title', '=', 'foo')->first(); // Constraints on the Comment model
```

> Q2:  *Is there a way to run the orm queries without running or render the application.*

**A2:**  - [Use the Artisan Console](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#tinker)

---

Read up on using the `php artisan tinker` with the link to the docs above.

Answer (score 1):

Answering with your question

```
// Answer 1 
Post::with('comments')->where([ 
    ['type', 1], 
    ['comments.title', '=', 'foo'] 
])->get();

// Answer 2 
// you can use tinker: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#tinker
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your help